# Trying to update the post in database.But getting Page not found (404)?And want to know how to update the data in database?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a blog app with django.When clicked on  a post it displays that post in separate page.In that i created edit and delete option.When i click on edit it returns edit option.But when i change some content and click on update it returns page not found error.

```
 #urls.py
 from django.urls import path,include
 from . import views

 urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.homepage),
    path('register',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login',views.login,name='login'),
    path('logout',views.logout,name='logout'),
    path('newpost',views.newpost,name="newpost"),
    path('<int:pk>', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit', views.edit, name='edit'),
    path('update', views.update, name='update'),
 ]

 <!---update.html page--->
  {% extends 'layout.html' %}
  {% block content %}
  <div class="box">
   <form action="updated" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <h3>Title of  Post</h3>
     <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="title" class="inputvalues" 
                                           value={{post.title}}>
     <h3>Description</h3>
     <textarea name="desc" style="width: 500px;margin: 0 auto;padding: 
                         5px;height:40%" >{{post.desc}}</textarea>
     <a href="update"></a>
          <button type="submit" id="lg" >Update</button>
    </a>
   </form>
  </div>
  {% endblock %}

   #views.py
    def edit(request,pk):
       post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
       return render(request,'update.html',{'post': post})

    def update(request):
       post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
       title=request.POST['title']
       desc=request.POST['desc']
       update = 
          Post(title=title,desc=desc,author_id=request.user.username)
       update.title= title
       update.desc= desc
       update.save();
       return redirect('indpost.html')
```

the url for displaying individual post is http://127.0.0.1:8000/48 where 48 is pk_id
the url when i click on edit is http://127.0.0.1:8000/48/edit
the url when i click on update is http://127.0.0.1:8000/48/updated

Comment: What do you think `return redirect('indpost.html')` will do?

Answer (score 0):

Your urlpattern has a typo:

```py
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.homepage),
    path('register',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login',views.login,name='login'),
    path('logout',views.logout,name='logout'),
    path('newpost',views.newpost,name="newpost"),
    path('<int:pk>', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit', views.edit, name='edit'),
    path('update', views.update, name='update'),
 ]
```

The last `path()` should be like this:

```py
path('updated', views.update, name='update'),
```

OR

You can change the `action` attribute on the HTML form:

```
  {% extends 'layout.html' %}
  {% block content %}
  <div class="box">
   <form action="update" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <h3>Title of  Post</h3>
     <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="title" class="inputvalues" 
                                           value={{post.title}}>
     <h3>Description</h3>
     <textarea name="desc" style="width: 500px;margin: 0 auto;padding: 
                         5px;height:40%" >{{post.desc}}</textarea>
     <a href="update"></a>
          <button type="submit" id="lg" >Update</button>
    </a>
   </form>
  </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have doubt when i click on edit the end of the url is 48/edit which matches with my url pattern but when i click on update the end of the url is 48/update which doesnt match with my urlpatterns because for update i gave only "update" and for edit i gave <int:pk>/edit

Comment: on the `action` attribute, try using `{% url 'update' %}`. That's because `action='update'` goes to a relative path

Comment: And one more when i go to change existing post and click on update its creating new Post not changing in existing post.Whats wrong in my code

Comment: if you have your original post on the `post` variable, just change the attributes on that variable and call `post.save()` what you're doing with the `update` variable is actually creating a whole new object with the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the pk in this line?

def update(request):
       post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
       #

you should first update the path like this:

```
path('<int:pk>/update', views.update, name='update') #I STRONGLY RECOMMEND USING A SLUG INSTEAD OF PK
```

and then update the method like this:

```
def update(request, pk):
```

in the return part, change it to :

```
return redirect('post_detail')
```

change the form action to:

{% url 'update' pk=post.pk %} #change post.pk to your pk

now you should be ok for the 404, but you are not updating the post, you created a new one, you can do:

```
post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
title=request.POST['title']
desc=request.POST['desc']
post.title= title
post.desc= desc
post.save()
```

and why do you even have a semicolon, lol